# How can i create a bridge on the OpenFlow swtich(not OVS) through OpenDaylight and OVSDB？

Tags: sdn, opendaylight, openvswitch

I can create a bridge on the OVS through ODL and ovsdb, but OpenFlow switch is not same as OVS, so I got a problem. When I send the configure through POSTMAN, I just get an echo packet with Wireshark. Does anybody know how to deal with this problem? My ODL version is Lithium sr2.

Comment: Thanks Buddy。i'm very appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Which OpenFlow switch are you using? Does it support OVSDB? The switch needs to support some configuration protocol (OVSDB or NetConf) in order to configure bridges on the switch. As OpenFlow is used to program flows on the switches, we cannot create bridges using OpenFlow protocol.

Comment: My switch support OVSDB，we can create bridges using the command line in ubuntu terminal。But,i want to create bridges through POSTMAN. you know。